# Adding dependencies data files loaded via __load__ with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an executable with PyInstaller which includes the dependency [`device_detector`](https://github.com/thinkwelltwd/device_detector).

When running the binary, I'm getting the error:

```
File "device_detector/device_detector.py", line 233, in parse
  File "device_detector/device_detector.py", line 312, in parse_bot
  File "device_detector/parser/parser.py", line 87, in parse
  File "device_detector/parser/parser.py", line 71, in _parse
  File "device_detector/yaml_loader.py", line 81, in regex_list
  File "device_detector/yaml_loader.py", line 63, in yaml_to_list
  File "device_detector/yaml_loader.py", line 39, in load_from_yaml
  File "~/pyenv/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 462, in get_data
    assert path.startswith(SYS_PREFIX + pyi_os_path.os_sep)
AssertionError
```

I assume this is because `device_detector` uses `__load__` to read `.yml` files during runtime, see this line [here](https://github.com/thinkwelltwd/device_detector/blob/master/device_detector/yaml_loader.py#L36).

I tried to include the missing `.yml` files by adding them to `datas` but this didn't work out.

Do I need to write some kind of hook for `device_detector`? I'm a bit lost on what to do next, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do your .yml files reside relatively to the exe file ?

Comment: they are a part of the `device_detector` dependency

Answer (score 0):

I went quickly through the device_detector code and my understanding is that it is loading local/device/normalize.yml. This can be managed by adding this to your build command

```
--add-data path_to_the_actual_normalize.yml\normalize.yml;local/device
```